# List contains duplicate Python solution

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, loops, duplicates

Can someone tell me if they see any problems with my solution below. It works fine on lists with duplicates `[1,2,2,3]`, but fails with examples with no duplicates: `[1,2,3,4]`

Thanks in advance!

```
class Solution(object):
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        i = 0
        dis = 0
        while i < len(nums):
            if nums[i] in nums:
                i+=1
            elif nums[i] not in nums:
                i+=1
                dis+=1

        if i == dis:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: `nums[i] in nums` will always be true. think about it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Explain what you want us to review, what the expected behavior is, what the issue you are observing is.

Comment: Thank you, @ashishsingh. So, `nums[i] in nums` will evaluate to True even if there's only one occurrence of the element?

Comment: @baokbaas yes it will

Comment: Hi, @dfundako. The behavior im looking for is: return True if the list contains more than a single occurrence of the same element, otherwise, return False. As is, it behaves as expected -returns True- with lists that have duplicates, but fails -returns also True- with lists that **dont't** have duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what i understood you want to return True is list contains duplicates and False when its not?
This can be done simply by converting the list into set, which cannot contain duplicates. Converting the list into set will remove all duplicates so if the set is smaller than the list, the list contains duplicates

```
class Solution(object):
   def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
      """
      :type nums: List[int]
      :rtype: bool
      """
      return not len(nums) == len(set(nums))
```

Comment: Thank you, jv95 for your response. Yes, that's exactly it: return True if the list contains more than a single occurrence of the same element, otherwise, return False. And yeah i realize a set should take care of it, i however want to understand why my code fails for the learning value.

Comment: Your code fails because if nums[i] in nums: is ALWAYS true

Comment: so after the while cycle will end, the i will have value of length of the list and dis will be always 0

Comment: If I answered your question please make sure to mark it as answer :)

Comment: you have, I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
class Solution(object):
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
        i = 0
        while i < len(nums):
            if nums[i] in [n for n in nums if nums.index(n) != i]: # If a number in nums equals to nums[i], but in a different index...
                return True # That means there's a duplicate
            i+=1
        return False # Only return False if the program iterated through all the numbers and haven't return True
a = Solution()

print(a.containsDuplicate([1,2,8,3]))
print(a.containsDuplicate([1,2,8,3,8]))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution(object):
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
        nums2 = set(nums)
        nums3 = list(nums2)
        if len(nums3) == len(nums):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This is effectively the same solution as in jv95's answer, written slightly differently. Please explain what are you adding to this Q&A with this similar answer.